# How do you connect a button to a database on ruby on rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, database

My project is basically a reminder app. The project is here: https://todo-app-back-end-prospeed.c9users.io/ . See the blue checkbox, I was researching how I could get the button to connect to the database. I wanted when the user checked the checkbox, the boolean is my data: `<Todo id: 24, description: "Publish project", pomodoro_estimate: 1, complete: nil,` **complete: nil** to turn true or false. Here is my index.html.erb:

`

```
<body>
<div class="container2">
    <h1 id ="list">Workshop Todo List</h1>
        <ul>
        <% @todos.each do |todo| %>
        <li>
            <label class="container">
            <input type="checkbox"/ checked="checked">
            <a href = "/show/<%= todo.id %>"><%= todo.description %></a>
            <span class="pomodoro-estimate"><%= todo.pomodoro_estimate %> pomodoro</span>
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
        </li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
        <a class="noColor" href="/new/"><input class="add-new-todo-button" type="submit" value="Add todo"/></a>
        <h1 id="Pomodoro-technique">What is a pomodoro estimate?</h1>
        <p id="Pomodoro-technique-info">
            <strong>1 pomodoro = 25 minutes + 5 minutes break.</strong><br>
            For more info: <a href="https://www.focusboosterapp.com/the-pomodoro-technique">https://www.focusboosterapp.com/the-pomodoro-technique</a>
            </p>
</div>
</body>
```

Feel free to point me in the right direction.

Comment: I don't unerstand the question. In which way do you want to connect it to the database?
What should the button do and where is it in the code?
You should check this https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers as there are many things in your code that should be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to add action on blue button. whenever its clicked it value should be changed
You can use form that include to do list id and and checkbox value of complete
you can add jquery when ever checkbox is clicked form should be submitted and on the backend there will be function that will save this value.

Answer (score 0):

To do this in Ruby on Rails, you will need several things:

- A route that matches what you want to do.
- A controller (`TodosController`) with a `toggle` or `update` action or something else which takes in a `todo_id`, a boolean `true/false`, finds the Todo, and sets the `complete` to true or false.
- A way to wire them all together via AJAX, so that when you toggle something on the web page, the database updates without you having to refresh the page.

Feel free to continue asking me questions and I'll see if I can still put you in the right direction.